# Set default folder in PhpStorm generate test

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to speed up my workflow for generating tests, and so after assigning shortcut for generate tests, I'd like to avoid selecting the directory every single time.

We have multiple tests directories based on type of the test, but most often I create tests in `/tests/unit`, which is like 6th of 9 directories that PhpStorm offers. And selecting this over and over really sucks.

[image]

Also, I found out that methods are selected based on where your caret is, so that when I'm in the `getComposerForDealIncomeType` function, it is checked by default. When the cursor is outside of any method, the `_construct` is pre-selected.

So my goal is following:

- set default directory
- pre-select all of the functions other than the constructor

Is that possible?

Comment: Neither one seems to be possible, unfortunately. In case of multiple test roots, it seems to pick the last one in the tree each time, which is an obvious usability issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-62021 As for the methods, you can choose all of them at once with `Ctrl+A | Space`, would that do?